# KaTex support in Rocket Chat

Tags: rocket.chat, katex

I feel almost stupid to ask this, but how does one enable KaTeX support in Rocket.Chat? I'm using this application in a constructive way to share some math expressions for study with my friends. What I tried so far:

1. Going through all of the settings in Rocket.Chat. I couldn't find anything KaTeX specific here.
2. Went to KaTeX.org and tried copy-pasting the scripts in the Install section, under `<head></head>` in Google chrome developer toolbox.

But, KaTeX simply does not render. Any help or inputs will be super-helpful. I am kind of lost.

Thanks,
Quasar.

Answer (score 5):

You ***literally*** have to escape the KaTex syntax like this:

`\[`  KaTeX Syntax `\]`

exactly as described by the ***hint*** underneath the message box:

[image]

Here are some examples: [Supported](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html)

> [image]

or

> [image]

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

In the Adminstration menu, go to Settings.
There is a search bar where you can simply type "Katex" which will filter the menu options to "Message" which has the Katex settings